# Controller class pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, asp.net-web-api

The `GetDropdownList()` function is being called on a couple of controllers based on this example and it may be called in many other controllers, so this code is being repeated. I was thinking of encapsulating this portion of code to the base class and call that base class in these controllers, but I got stuck and don't know how to implement it. Can you please show me a way using SOLID principles?

```
public interface IDropdownListEntity
{
    string Value { get; set; }
    string Text { get; set; }
}

public sealed class DropdownListEntity: IDropdownListEntity
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class CountryController : ApiController
{
    //Returns the list of countries
    public IEnumerable<IDropdownListEntity> GetDropdownList()
    {
        CountryStore store = new CountryStore();

        return store.SimpleSortedListByName<DropdownListEntity>();
    }
}

public class CityController : ApiController
{
    //Returns the list of cities
    public IEnumerable<IDropdownListEntity> SortedListForDropdown()
    {
        CityStore store = new CityStore();

        return store.SimpleSortedListByName<DropdownListEntity>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do your stores share an interface or base class?

Comment: @Andy: yes, the stores are inherited from a base class and that base class is inherited from couple of interfaces. I think, I know what you are thinking based on your question but I will not spill water onto your thoughts... Lol

Comment: In fact, I did try to use one of the interface which is plugged into store's base class but that didn't work for me... Maybe I did it the wrong way.. Am a beginner!

Comment: I have also thought of using Reflection, but not sure again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Web API should not be bound to a particular UI**

   API calls should not bound to a user interface requirement, so that it could be used in multiple places without any addition requirement. In the above code, it is returning a list of dropdownlist values rather than a list of entities.

   Your controller code may look like this:

   ```
   public class ConstantsController : ApiController
   {
       private readonly IConstantRepository _constantRepository;

       public ConstantsController(IConstantRepository constantRepository)
       {
           _constantRepository = constantRepository;
       }


       [Route("Constants/City")]
       [HttpGet]
       public IEnumerable<City> GetCity()
       {
           return _constantRepository.GetCity();
       }


       [Route("Constants/Country")]
       [HttpGet]
       public IEnumerable<Country> Country()
       {
           return _constantRepository.GetCountry();
       }
   }
   ```

   Note: I am using Web API 2 for this code.

   This code can be used by any kind of application like this:

   > http://yoururl/Constants/Country
2. **Use a DI container to inject dependencies into your controller**

   Use Unity or a simple injector to inject dependencies. It will help you to isolate components.

   ```
   public interface IConstantRepository
   {
       IEnumerable<City> GetCity();

       IEnumerable<Country> GetCountry();
   }
   ```

Also, include unit tests in your applications.

Comment: How the the implementation of _constantRepository.GetCity() and _constantRepository.GetCountry() would look like?

Comment: It should call your db and get the data. If you are using Entity Framework , it would look something like _dbContext.City.Get() .

Comment: So, you are suggesting me to group all the constants together, maybe into a single repository called 'Constants'?

Comment: Yes , If it is a master list , you can group those in one class , It is up to your design requirement.

Comment: Ok. The reason I have chosen to implement IDropdownListEntity is because I thought it's light weight and transfer less bytes to the client, meaning the entity has only (Text and Value properties). 

But, if I return the original entity it may contain a lot of other fields and that's going to be irrelevant in this particular case, meaning values for other fields would be transferred to the client as null (using Json).

Maybe, I should rephrase the (Text and Value) to (Id, Name) or there is something wrong with my thought process?

Comment: You can control irrelevant field by introducing a DataContract which will contain all the necessary field only. In that case you need write a mapper and DataContract though but which is fine